# Android/PhoneGap debugging: app not updated

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to use PhoneGap with Android. In the Sample that I run the main app opens an html file:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

Now if I change something in the html page, Android always shows the previous content.
Is it possible that the output files (resources in that case) are not updated?

Also if I change the name of the html file in /assets/newName.html and into .loadUrl nothing changes.

Thank you, F.

Comment: You should be able to tell from the console if it is re-generating and uploading the .apk file or just re-launching the installed version.  If changing a "data" file does not result in apk regeneration but changing a .java file does, something may not be right in the project setup.

Answer (score 1):

I'm determined to find a proper answer to this, at the moment changes in the assets dir do not trigger a rebuild.

At the moment I'm slapping a new line in the Activity.java code to force a rebild/deploy..

Will update once I've looked for a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

I see this sometimes when I add a data file to a project in eclipse.

If you think you pkg isnt being updated (re-built) then just rebuild it manually. If your using eclipse just do project->clean and select the project you want to clean. it'll rebuild automatically and include anything that was missed out.

Comment: I did it but nothing changes. Consider, I tried with Eclipse and Intellij IDEA 10.5 too. Same problem... should be something in the configuration...

Answer (score 0):

OK Guys found.

The tutorial in the wiki.phonegap.com is obsolete.

Samples instead are updated!

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you give link for improving your andwer?

Comment: sorry too long time ago... forgot.